# Does kats support convariates in time series forcasting

Tags: time-series, kats

I want to use kats to forecast sales of product we will sell.
One of the key indicators of how much we will sell is how much we spend on advertising leading up to a given day.
We also know this for the coming weeks.
So we want to provide that this at prediction time to improve prediction accuracy.

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/facebookresearch/Kats/blob/main/tutorials/kats_201_forecasting.ipynb.

I don't see any way of giving the model this information.
Is this something that is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question! For the current available models in Kats, 'prophet' supports covariates. User can specify the name of covariates in the `ProphetParams` and feed a multivariate `TimeSeriesData` (containing the corresponding covariates) into `ProphetModel`. To generate forecasts, the future covariate information should be passed as a `pd.Dataframe` object like
`pm.predict(steps = 10, future=pd.DataFrame({'ds':..., 'covariate':...}))`.

Comment: I don't see a constructor parameter or a method on ProphetParams to specify covariates. 
https://facebookresearch.github.io/Kats/api/kats.models.prophet.html#kats.models.prophet.ProphetParams
Can you let me know the name of the method or constructor parameter.?